# animejs glow a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Basically, I have a div which I want it to glow. I achieved this using CSS but want to switch to javascript.

Here is my CSS method:

```
@keyframes glowing{
            0% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae; }
            50% { box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #001bae; }
            100% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae;}
}
.CountryLoc{
            position:absolute;
            height:2px;
            width:2px;
            background:#001bae;
            border-radius: 100%;
            display:block;
            box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px #001bae;
            animation: glowing 2000ms infinite;
}
```

If you want a Live view of my current method, visit: https://neehack.com/map

I want to switch above to javascript animejs.

I was able to fadeout the box-shadow glow using below script, but it do not glow up/fade up again to `100% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae;}`

```
 anime({
                targets:'.CountryLoc',
                'box-shadow':'0 0 6px 0px #001bae',
                duration:1000,
                loop:true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Anime.js, but with the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API), you can translate your CSS animations fairly easy. The example below takes in your keyframes and uses [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) to set the animation.

```
const keyframes = [
  { boxShadow: '0 0 3px 0px #001bae' },
  { boxShadow: '0 0 6px 2px #001bae' },
  { boxShadow: '0 0 3px 0px #001bae' }
];

const timing = {
  duration: 2000,
  iterations: Infinity;
};

const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.CountryLoc');
targets.forEach(target => target.animate(keyframes, timing);
```

Though it is unclear why you want to make the switch. CSS is most of the the most performant option and you don't need any dynamic animations.